# Vibration stops and I don't know why

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, wakelock, android-vibration

I have a service that launches an activity when a specific event happens. This activity then starts a vibrator. It all works fine when I am in my main activity, however, when the device is locked it only vibrates once and then stops. Here is a sample of my code Service code

```
public class VService extends Service { 

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    getV();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public class getV() {
    if (value > 10) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Alarm.class);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                                     
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT):    
        alarmIntent.putExtra("v", value);
        getApplication().startActivity(alarmIntent);
}
}
```

The logic to my Alarm class is as follows...
OnCreate starts the vibration using

```
vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); long[]
pattern = {0, 100, 1000}; vib.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

OnDestory stops the vib using vib.cancel(); 
The only other places vib.cancel() is called is in the handler checking if v is less than 10, but this can't be the reason because I haven't made the v less than 10. vib.cancel();  is also called with a button press.

Areas I've looked at- This only happens when the screen is off, so maybe it has something to do with my onCreate where I do the wakelock release?

```
Runnable releaseWakelock = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

            if (mWakeLock != null && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                mWakeLock.release();
            }
        }
    };
```

Or my on resume which basically calls the same thing but uses a power service to turn on the screen.

So my question is, why does my vibrator only vibrate once when the AlarmClass is launched while the screen is off, but works perfectly fine when the screen is on? I've been trying to figure this out, thanks for any input or help.

**EDIT:** The runnable gets executed in onCreate of the Alarm class. The following is executed in the onResume class.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

    // Acquire wakelock
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (mWakeLock == null) {
        mWakeLock = pm
                .newWakeLock(
                        (PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                                | PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP),
                        TAG);
    }

    if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        Log.i(TAG, "Wakelock aquired!!");
    }
```

Comment: This is my first time posting, so any tips on question format or etiquette are welcome.

Comment: Good start but can you show how you acquire the WakeLock, and when your releaseWakeLock runnable gets started?

Comment: @DaveMorrissey I edited my question to show the answer to your question. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Calling that runnable in your onCreate means that flags are cleared almost immediately, so the activity won't keep the screen on. Maybe I'm misreading this.

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining it poorly. The activity launches correctly whether the screen is on or off. The screen stays lit until the user performs an action. The problem is that whenever the activity is launched when the screen is off, the device only vibrates once, when it should be vibrating continuously. @DaveMorrissey